# mysqli_real_escape_string() returns empty string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string() on an email address, and it returns an empty string. It does this with any email address.

```
<?php
//from previous page - submitted by user.
$_POST['email']="aehmlo@aehmlo.com";
$_POST['password']='mypass1234';




//Link, I can verify it works.
$mysql_info=array(
     "url"=>"url",
     "username"=>"username",
     "password"=>"password",
     "database"=>"database"
);
$link=mysqli_connect($mysql_info['url'],$mysql_info['username'],$mysql_info['password'],$mysql_info['database']);


//Now I attempt to sanitize the user input.
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
$password=sha1(mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['password']));
var_dump($email);
var_dump($password);?>
```

My table's collation is "latin1_swedish_ci".

Comment: Sorry, my question is: Why does this return an empty string, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Could you please add error handling to your code?

Comment: You mean like error_reporting(E_ALL);? Already did. Nothing.

Comment: Please follow the error handler for checking the connection in my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your connection is empty (`$link`), it will return an empty string. I tested this and it worked fine. I would recommend that you add error handling to your connection and enable error reporting.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$_POST['email'] = "aehmlo@aehmlo.com";

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);

var_dump($email);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**Result**

```
string(17) "aehmlo@aehmlo.com"
```

Comment: Turns out my web host changed the socket's location without telling me. Thanks.

Comment: It's always best to implement an error handler. In this case, it would have pointed you to the connection.

Comment: I had one implemented, then took it out for production.

Comment: You can turn on/off error reporting in the script so that when it goes into production you can disable it.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and found that my character set was set to latin. Solved by putting

```
$con->set_charset("utf8");
```

before the real_escape_string. Would be mysqli_set_charset in procedural style.